# javascript regex multiple pattern search

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write the regex to search the string

String :

```
{@CSS resources=",resources/css/page.css,/resources/css/global.css ," /}
```

Regex:

```
{@CSS resources=\s*"(.*?)"\s*\/}|(^,)|(,$)
```

Need to find leading and trailing commas with "resources"

Comment: `\{@CSS resources=\s*",[^"]*"\s*\/}`

Comment: are you trying to do the replace?

Comment: NO, I want to match any leading or trailing commas and spaces between {@CSS resources= and /} with in doube quotes (,resources/css/page.css,/resources/css/global.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
{@CSS resources=\s*"(\s*,\s*)*(.*?)(\s*,\s*)*"\s*\/}
```

and replace with `{@CSS resources="$2" /}`

Comment: I want to match any leading or trailing commas and spaces between `{@CSS resources= and /}` with in doube quotes `(,resources/css/page.css,/resources/css/global.css)`

Comment: @BharathBhuvan That's what the first and third capture groups do !